# facebookAuthCredential.idToken is null in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-facebook-login

I successfully integrated facebook login in android and ios, I also getting facebook access token on login but getting null in token id. Below is the code

```
  Future<UserCredential> signInWithFacebook() async {
    // Trigger the sign-in flow
    final LoginResult loginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

    // Create a credential from the access token
    final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
        FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResult.accessToken!.token);
    print(facebookAuthCredential.idToken); //Here getting null

    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    return FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get an `idToken` at this point with Facebook authentication flow, only `accessToken`. Use the following code skeleton to manage Facebook sign-in and evaluate the results at specific lines with breakpoints:

```
Future<UserCredential> signInWithFacebook() async {
  final LoginResult loginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

  if (loginResult.status == LoginStatus.success) {
    final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.accessToken!;
    final OAuthCredential credential =
        FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token);
    try {
      return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // manage Firebase authentication exceptions
    } catch (e) {
      // manage other exceptions
    }
  } else {
      // login was not successful, for example user cancelled the process
  }
}
```

Then you can call this function with `await`, and once the future is completed, you can access user data:

```
final userCredential = await signInWithFacebook();
if (userCredential != null) {
    // here you will have your Firebase user in:
    // userCredential.user
    final idToken = userCredential.user!.getIdToken();
}
```

Comment: what should i `return` at the end ?

Comment: It depends on what do you need. In the above code a `UserCredential` future is returned, and the user will be within the returned value in `.user`. I will add some lines to the answer. But you can return whatever you want.

Comment: So it is not possible to get token id with this plugin package

Comment: @MohammedNabil It is possible, after you have your user. Like: `final token = await userCredential.user!.getIdToken()`